# Centering color around 0 with RColorBrewer

Tags: r, image, plot

So I want to visualise a matrix with colors like this

```
library(RColorBrewer)
vec = rbinom(10000,1,0.1)
n = sum(vec)
vec = ifelse(vec == 1, rnorm(n), 0)
mat = matrix(vec,100,100)
image(t(mat)[,nrow(mat):1],
      col=brewer.pal(8,"RdBu"),
      xaxt= "n", yaxt= "n", frame.plot=T,
      useRaster = TRUE
)
```

Which gives me the plot

[image: Example plot]

But I want the colors to be "centered around 0". By that I mean that I want the value zero to be white and positive/negative values be red/blue (or blue/red it doesn't matter). Any ideas if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

The function `bluered` in the `gplots` package does this.  You can make your color palette as:

```
library(gplots) # not to be confused with `ggplot2`, which is a very different package
color_palette <- bluered(9) # change the number to adjust how many shades of blue/red you have.  Even numbers will assign white to two bins in the middle.
```

To force them to be centered in the middle, you might use the `heatmap.2` function, also in `gplots` - just don't have it do any clustering:

```
heatmap.2(mat,
  Rowv = FALSE,
  Colv = FALSE, 
  dendrogram = 'none',
  trace = 'none',
  col = bluered, # this can take a function
  symbreaks = TRUE, # this is the key  value for symmetric breaks
)
```

to stick with the `image` function, you need to manually set the breaks.  The following code will get that for you:

```
pos_breaks <- quantile(abs(mat), probs = seq(0, 1, length.out = 5))
centered_breaks <- c(rev(-pos_breaks[-1]), pos_breaks)
```

Comment: Perfect! It actually works with the image function without the breaks. When I try the breaks (in case I need them another time) I get the erro message "Error in image.default(t(prec_temp)[, nrow(prec_temp):1], col = color_palette,  : 
  must have one more break than colour". But if I change the number of colors (from 9 to 8) then the colors are way of.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution without any additional packages.  In your code you did not assign the values from the vec variable to any of the eight color bins.  You need to cut the vec array into your eight bins and then assign each bin to a color and then plot:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
vec = rbinom(10000,1,0.1)
n = sum(vec)
vec = ifelse(vec == 1, rnorm(n), 0)
mat = matrix(vec,100,100)

#cut the original data into 9 groups
cutcol<-cut(vec, 9)
#Create color palette with white as the center color
colorpal<-brewer.pal(8,"RdBu")
colorpal<-c(colorpal[1:4], "#FFFFFF", colorpal[5:8])

#assign the data to the 9 color groups
color<-colorpal[cutcol]
#create the color matrix to match the original data
colormat<-matrix(color,100,100)

#plot with the assigned colors
image(t(mat)[,nrow(mat):1],
      col=colormat,
      xaxt= "n", yaxt= "n", frame.plot=T,
      useRaster = TRUE
)

#check color assignment
#hist(vec)
#hist(as.numeric(cutcol), breaks=8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't make the 0 values white though?

Comment: See my revision above needed to add white to the color palette.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to `heatmap2`, you could use `pheatmap`:

```
library(pheatmap)
pheatmap(mat,
         color = brewer.pal(7,"RdBu"),
         border_color = NA,
         cluster_rows = FALSE,
         cluster_cols = FALSE)
```

You can also hide the legend if you wish with `legend = FALSE`, which would yield a similar result to your image call, but with white being 0.

Comment: I didn't know pheatmap could do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the `ggplot2` package with manual scaling ([Ref](https://www.hvitfeldt.me/blog/center-continuous-palettes-in-ggplot2/))

```r
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

set.seed(2020)
vec <- rbinom(10000, 1, 0.1)
n <- sum(vec)
vec <- ifelse(vec == 1, rnorm(n), 0)
mat <- matrix(vec, 100, 100)

# convert to long format
df <- melt(mat)
summary(df)
#>       Var1             Var2            value          
#>  Min.   :  1.00   Min.   :  1.00   Min.   :-2.916137  
#>  1st Qu.: 25.75   1st Qu.: 25.75   1st Qu.: 0.000000  
#>  Median : 50.50   Median : 50.50   Median : 0.000000  
#>  Mean   : 50.50   Mean   : 50.50   Mean   : 0.000772  
#>  3rd Qu.: 75.25   3rd Qu.: 75.25   3rd Qu.: 0.000000  
#>  Max.   :100.00   Max.   :100.00   Max.   : 3.214787

### default
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
  geom_raster() +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

Rescale

```r
# set the limits of the palette so that zero is in the middle of the range.
limit <- max(abs(df$value)) * c(-1, 1)

p1 + 
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = 'RdBu', limit = limit)
```

[image]

```r
# test with the scico package 
# https://github.com/thomasp85/scico
library(scico)
p1 + 
  scale_fill_scico(palette = "roma", limit = limit)
```

[image]

```r
# test with the rcartocolor package 
# https://github.com/Nowosad/rcartocolor
library(rcartocolor)
p1 + 
  scale_fill_carto_c(palette = 'Earth', limit = limit)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>